# how to check django_tables2 object empty/null?

Tags: python, django

The problem I'm trying to solve:
Display a search bar only when the table `my_table` is not empty, else, hide it.

Here's my views.py:

```
def my_table(request):
    model1 = Model1.objects.all().filter(Q(some_query))
    table = MyTable(model1)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    if not table:
        print "table is empty"
        table = None
    else:
        print "table is not empty."
    return render(request, 'my_table.html', {'my_table':table,})
```

Here's my `my_table.html`:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% if my_table  %}
Number of entries: {{ my_table|length }}.
<section>
    <form method="post" action=".">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" class="search-query span80" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Type to search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button> 
    </form>
</section>
{% else %}
<!-- There's no my_table. -->
{% endif%}

{% render_table my_table %}
```

However, this table object in `my_table(request)` views.py contains really nothing, and it doesn't render anything in the html, but it's just not empty, and displays the search bar.
Please advise. Where I'm doing it wrong?

In response to comments, here's MyTable code:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    entry1 = tables.Column(verbose_name="Entry 1")
    entry2 = tables.Column(verbose_name="Entry 2")
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        empty_text = "There is no entry record."
        order_by = "entry1"
        orderable = True
        sequence = ('entry1', 'entry2')
        fields = ('entry1', 'entry2')
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue", "style": "width:380px"}
```

And here's the code for MyModel:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    entry1 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11L, db_column='Entry1', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    entry2 = models.CharField(max_length=11L, db_column='Entry2', blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
class Meta:
    db_table = 'my_table'
```

Comment: Did you tried `if not table[0]` ?

Comment: Thanks, but my table does not support indexing.

Comment: What does it contain ?

Comment: Thanks, I've added MyTable code in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you views.py you can use:

```
if table.data.data.__len__ > 0:
```

and in your template you can use:

```
{% if table.data|length > 0 %}
do whatever you want here...
{% endif %}
```